# Run a shell command via tower-cli

Tags: command-line, ansible, ansible-tower

Ansible CLI allows to run a custom shell command (done implicitly using the default module "ansible.builtin.command"):

```
ansible myhost -a "/bin/mycommand"
```

Is it possible to do the same via `tower-cli` aka `awx-cli`?

EDIT: answers that use the `awx` CLI tool are acceptable; however, I'd prefer solutions that use `tower-cli`/`awx-cli`.

Comment: Regarding "_I'd prefer solutions that use `tower-cli`/`awx-cli`_" and since the `awx` command is part of the product [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx), do you mean exactly the commands [`tower-cli` (deprecated)](https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli) and `awx-cli` from [awxkit (Python library that backs the provided awx command line client.)](https://github.com/ansible/awx/tree/devel/awxkit)? I ask because according [Red Hat Solution #4971631](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4971631) is command `awx` is actually the "`awx-cli`".

Comment: Yes.  On my system (CentOS 7.9) these commands are two tiny Python scripts: a single call `load_entry_point('ansible-tower-cli==3.3.9', 'console_scripts', 'tower-cli')()` for `tower-cli`.  `awx-cli` is identical except for the third arg of the function, which calls `..., 'awx-cli')()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is yes.

According the Ansible Tower CLI [Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/reference.html), it is possible to do an [`awx ad_hoc_commands create`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/reference.html#awx-ad-hoc-commands) resulting into a [Job](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/jobs.html) similar as others.

The parameter for `--module_name` would be `shell` or `command` and if configured for

> ANSIBLE MODULES ALLOWED FOR AD HOC JOBS List of modules allowed to be used by ad-hoc jobs.

under [Settings / Jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/configure_tower_in_tower.html#jobs).

The parameter for `--module_args` whould be your command as usual.